# Which is the correct phrase to be filled in the blank in the sentence, "would have been", "had been" or "have been?"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, past-perfect

Which is the correct phrase to be filled in the blank in the sentence, "would have been", "had been" or "have been?"

> I ………… intending to stop smoking even before I got this bad cough.

Also I would be thankful if someone help me understand the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrase is "had been." The speaker uses the past perfect continuous to tell us that the bad cough from which she now suffers ("this cough") did not alone cause her to stop smoking, because her intention to stop preceded the bad cough.